# ListPlot and list manipulation

Tags: plotting

I have the following list

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 9}, {3, 8, 27}}
```

I would like to plot second part with respect to first part but third part with respect to *twice* the first part in the same plot. I tried:

```
ListLinePlot[{data[[All, {1, 2}]], data[[All, {2 #1, 3}]]}]
```

which does not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does `ListLinePlot[{data[[All, {1, 2}]], data[[All, {1, 3}]].DiagonalMatrix[{2, 1}]}, PlotRange -> All]` suit your needs?

Comment: Yes, this works. I have a further question: can I also add a constant also to first part? That is, plot part 3 w.r.t. 5+ part 1?

Comment: You might be interested in `TranslationTransform[]` and `ScalingTransform[]`, then; e.g. `TranslationTransform[{5, 0}][data[[All, {1, 3}]]]`.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 2):

This method is very general and goes beyond translation and scaling:

```
ListLinePlot[{{#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ data, {2 #[[1]], #[[3]]} & /@ data}]
```